# Reduce elements in a java list using Java8 streams

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a java list that contains elements like below:

Input List name is itemsList:

```
List<Items> itemsList ;
```

Items class:

```
List<String> Identifier;
List<String> websites;
```

Input Elements for the list:

```
Identifier    websites
 id1,id2      site1
 id2,id3       site3
 id5           site5
 id1           site6
 id5          site7 
 id6           site8
```

Result list:

```
   Identifier         websites
     id1,id2,id3      site1,site3,site6   
     id5                site5,site7
     id6                site8
```

As you can see from the result :
Identifier should be grouped together if anyone Identifier is present from the other row and all websites should be combined together as well

Here is what I tried :

```
    itemsList.stream().reduce((v1, v2) ->
    {
        //see if identofier overlaps
        if (!Collections.disjoint(v1.getIdentifier(), (v2.getIdentifier()))) {
            v1.getIdentifier().addAll(v2.getIdentifier());
            v1.getwebsites().addAll(v2.getwebsites());
     
        } 
        return v1;
    });
```

my solution doesn't help much..As it only reduces the first row.
I know it is not an easy one to solve.

Comment: I am reading your input as `id1 -> site1, site2`, `id2 -> site1, site2` and *then* : union `id1` and `id2`. Is that correct?

Comment: but how do you know that id1 and id2 are to be joined because it is now :
id1 -> site1, site2, id2 -> site1, site2,
the ids has to be in the other row for them to be joined. if they are separated as 1 id per row , join is not possible correct

Comment: The relation between ids and sites is many to one.. sorry I updated my input data in the question.

Comment: They rather seem to be many-to-many. I haven’t thought it through, but my immediate idea is that streams are poorly suited for this.

Comment: You can't really `reduce` this structure. Because you want to end up with disjoint sets such as `{id1, id2, id3}`, `{id6}`, `{id13, id17}`,.... I would use UF to get the disjoint sets and then just do a set `addAll()` to get the sites for each set.

Comment: @jrook sorry what is UF?

Comment: @OleV.V.  do you have a suggestion? any SQL joins?

Comment: @Coder123 , sorry, I meant Union-Find.

Comment: What is the result of your attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple approach:

1. Create a result list and initialize it to empty.
2. Iterate over the input list. For each input element:

   1. Find all elements in the result list that holds either an ID or a site (or both) from the input element.
   2. Combine (reduce) them into one result list member.
   3. Also add the input element.

Use a classical loop, no stream operation.